# How to access multiple client in VB.Net Socket Programming

Tags: vb.net, sockets

hey i creating a lan based application in vb.net,I'm already created a server and a client
and make a release build of both programmer.

**Server code**

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Module Module1

    Dim isActive As Boolean

    Sub Main()

        Dim port As Integer 'this is port number 
        Dim localAddr As IPAddress 'Ip Address
        Dim server As TcpListener ' for use tcp/ip protocol
        Dim client As TcpClient
        Dim aString As String
        Dim negotiateStream As Security.NegotiateStream = Nothing
        Dim d As DictionaryEntry
        Try
            port = 8888
            localAddr = IPAddress.Loopback 'return the ipaddress of self

            'creating the server
            server = New TcpListener(localAddr, port)
            server.Start()
            Console.WriteLine("Server ready")

            'this is a block method, it will wait for new connection
            'before continuing
            client = server.AcceptTcpClient
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to " & IPAddress.Parse(CType(client.Client.LocalEndPoint, IPEndPoint).Address.ToString).ToString)
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to " & client.ToString)
            Do
                Console.Write(" Ready to quit? (y/n)")
                aString = Console.ReadLine()
                If aString <> "y" Then
                    'do something
                End If
            Loop Until aString = "y" ' Or aString = "n"
        Catch e As System.Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Can't create the server : " + e.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

**Client code**

```
Imports System.Net ' for IPAddress
Imports System.Net.Sockets 'for TcpListener
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

    Dim aString As String
    Dim port As Integer 'this is the port number
    Dim localAddr As IPAddress ' this is the IP address
    Dim client As TcpClient ' This is for the TCP/IP Protocol
    Dim networkStream As NetworkStream 'use to send/recieve data

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ConnectToServer(localAddr, port)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = "Press button to connect with the server"
        port = 8888
        localAddr = IPAddress.Loopback
        Button2.Enabled = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub ConnectToServer(ByRef ipaddr, ByRef port)
        Try
            client = New TcpClient(localAddr.ToString, port)
            TextBox1.Text = "Connencted to : " & IPAddress.Parse(CType(client.Client.LocalEndPoint, IPEndPoint).Address.ToString).ToString & " "
            networkStream = client.GetStream()
            Button1.Enabled = False
            Button2.Enabled = True
        Catch e As Exception
            MsgBox(e.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim outStream As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Message from Client$")
        networkStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
        networkStream.Flush()
    End Sub
End Class
```

now when i start the server and connect the client1 to the server a message is print on console of server like that "connect to client *_*" but now it open another client(client2) and then  connect it to the server no new message is show for the client2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because

```
client = server.AcceptTcpClient
```

is a waiting for a connection and after it gets 1, it does not wait for another.

To wait for more, you could put this inside of a loop but you open a whole can of worms.  You now need to track connections (maybe in an array or something) and then keep the loop going so you can always be waiting for more connections and processing messages from other connections. But, because you cannot wait, and keep the loop going, you need to make this multi-threaded.

Looks like your simple app just became complicated but at least I hope I gave you some ideas to plan this out a little further.